# How to get global variables in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I mean the preset global variables, such as `global` in Node and `window` in browser. How can I get them?

The underscore get the global variable as below:

```
var root = typeof self == 'object' && self.self === self && self || typeof global == 'object' && global.global === global && global || this || {};
root._ = _;
```

Comment: This is for angular but you can configure it to your needs.
https://netbasal.com/how-to-integrate-recaptcha-in-your-angular-forms-400c43344d5c

Comment: @atilkan Thx for ur answering, I'll see it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 declare var global: any;
 declare var window: any;

 var root: any = null;

 try {
    root = typeof global === 'object' ? global : window;
 } catch(e) {
    // catch is when you are executing in custom V8 where it is
    // configured to throw instead of assuming undefined..
 }

 if (root) {

       // either global or window is present here..
 }
```

Comment: Thx, I do it like what u say and it really works, but I still dont know why it happens.Is there any instructions can recommended for me?Thx for u again!